# Change image in media library at specific time

Tags: media, automation

Is it possible to bulk change images (just the images in the media library) at a specified time?

For example, I'd like images `a.jpg`, `b.jpg`, `c.jpg` to change with `a1.jpg`, `b1.jpg`, `c1.jpg` tomorrow at 8:00am.

Comment: I wonder what problem you're trying to solve here - maybe there are other ways?

Comment: Say the image "switch" has to be done at 3.00am... the user doesn't want to be up until it's 3am...

Comment: I mean, why not have both image versions available, and just switch them in the HTML output? (I don't know the actual setup though)